# Relation between the oxidation state of central atom and its coordination number in a complex compound?

Tags: coordination-compounds

We know for a complex say $\ce{[Co(NH3)3Cl3]}$ we have $\ce{Co^{3+}}$  and its coordination number here is 6. And for this if we know either oxidation state or coordination number then other is fixed. So is there a way to figure out relation between them and for other compounds like $\ce{[Ni(CO)4]}$, $\ce{K2[PtCl4]}$, and $\ce{[Pt(NH3)2Cl3]}$.

Comment: Your premise " if we know either oxidation state or coordination number then other is fixed" is completely not true.

Answer (score 2):

The hexaaquacobalt(II) complex $\ce{[Co(H2O)6]^2+}$ is octahedral.

The tetrachloridocobaltate(II) complex $\ce{[CoCl4]^2-}$ is tetrahedral.

knowing the oxidation state does not allow prediction of the coordination number or vice-versa.

Comment: How [Co(H2O)6]2+ is possible, considering the outer electronic configuration of cobalt (4s2)(3d7)(4p0) if it is in its +2 oxidation state i.e. (4s0)(3d7)(4p0) it's not possible for it to accommodate 6 ligands and thus to have coordination number of 6

Comment: @PrashantSingh Of course it is possible, it is known, isolated and characterised. $\mathrm d^7$ is a perfectly fine electronic configuration of a transition metal. Indeed, you can find all eleven possible configurations from $\mathrm d^0$ to $\mathrm d^{10}$.

Answer (score -2):

There is no relation between the oxidation state of the central atom and its coordination number. The complex compound you just mentioned is a good example. It was [Co(NH3)6]Cl3 and it contains Cobalt at the oxidation state +3. In water the corresponding ion will be formed : [Co(NH3)6]^3+. But a similar ion may be formed with Cobalt(II) and the same number of 6 NH3 molecules as ligands. It will yield the ion [Co(NH3)6]^2+ and the salt [Co(NH3)6]Cl2.

Comment: But considering the outer electronic configuration of cobalt (4s2)(3d7)(4p0) if it is in its +2 oxidation state i.e. (4s0)(3d7)(4p0) it's not possible for it to accommodate 6 ligands and thus to have coordination number of 6.